# Zend Framework 1.12 Module specific bootstrap classes.

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have the following directory structure for my application:

```
application
   modules
      default
        controllers
        models
        views
        Bootstrap.php
     test
       controllers
       models
       views
       Bootstrap.php
```

Below is the code of module specific bootstrap files:

```
//default/bootstrap.php
class Default_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initMessageDefault(){
        echo "called default module's bootstrap file";
    }
}

//test/bootstrap.php
class Test_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
  protected function _initMessageTest(){
    echo "called test module's bootstrap file";
  }
}
```

Now if I call the default controller I.e. www.domain.com/index I can see following output:

```
called default module's bootstrap file
called test module's bootstrap file
```

My question is why the bootstrap file of both the modules is getting called? Shouldn't just the boostrap file of the default module be called when I call the default module?

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is intended. Bootstraps are for application *initialization*, all bootstraps are run on every request.

If you're looking to do something only for the current module what you probably want is a controller plugin. These are also run on every request but you can check the current module in there and then run some custom code.